# Determine Line Number from Byte Offset in a text file

Tags: java, io

I currently have a scenario where I know the byte offset of a text file. I want to know is there anyway in which I can determine the line number from the byte offset. The records in the text file are not of fixed length, in which case I would have divided the offset by the width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot determine the line number from byte offset unless all the lines are a uniform length. However you can scan for newlines and keep track of them to calculate the offset in the file.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like;

```
String fullTextFile = loadTextFile();
String section = fullTextFile.substring(0, byteOffset);
String reduced = section.replaceAll("[^\n]*","");
int lineNumber = reduced.length();
```

I'm not entirely sure how legal that regex is, but it shouldn't require much tweaking.

Comment: It does, the other approach would be to use a `Reader` and `readLine()` until you hit the byte offset, counting lines as you go.

Comment: Yes, I cannot load the file in the memory. I am using hadoop to process this large text file, which spits out offsets along with the record. I was wondering if I can track the line numbers in this way but looks like that is not possible. May be I have to think of another approach other than sorting all the offsets which will be highly inefficient