# Find line by character position

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string of around 4MB (4 million characters) and around 30.000 lines in a variable. Next I have the index of a character, lets say `3605506`, what would be the quickest most efficient way to find on which line this character is? I need to do this hundreds of times after each other, so that's why it's relatively important it's efficient.

Comment: I take it the lines are of variable length?

Comment: @nnnnnn Yeah, I have now implemented a really inefficient temporary solution where I loop over the lines every time and compare with the character position... but it's both too slow and feels really bad.

Comment: This question sound similar to -> [Determine Line Number from Byte Offset in a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13609535/determine-line-number-from-byte-offset-in-a-text-file).  
You need to scan through the file and count how many new-lines you discover as you approach your byte offset.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl: The OP looks for a JavaScript solutions, not Java

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, though this was Java, because File IO should not be processed on the client side. Especially if you need an "efficient" algorithm.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl That's what I am doing now which is terrible as far as performance goes... weh :( Was hoping for some easy miracle solution, oh well, guess the linked answer stating 'not possible' actually makes a lot of sense. Still though, I think it should be somehow possible to set up an index of new lines or something, oh well, if I figure it out at some point I guess I will come back here~

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl And regarding your second comment, sometimes you do if your application needs to work offline ;-)

Comment: "I need to do this hundreds of times after each other" - all on the same large string, or on different ones?

Comment: @user5354681 Mark Reed asks the question that is really on point. If the string is the same, the accepted solution really does give you a brute force solution. You traverse that string for EVERY lookup. You split the string for EVERY lookup. You add the character counts for each line for EVERY lookup. If the string is the same, this is a lot of repeated work that is unnecessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pass the string and and index to the below function. It splits the string based on new line characters and checks if the count has passed the index value.

```
function getlineNumberofChar(data,index) {
    var perLine = data.split('\n');
    var total_length = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < perLine.length; i++) {
        total_length += perLine[i].length;
        if (total_length >= index)
            return i + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't upvote, but to my sincere surprise your code actually is more performant than my own simple loop: http://jsperf.com/line-from-position

Comment: Can you check if this statement  returns the answer ? 
data.substring(0, index).split('\n').length

Comment: Except I failed to realize that your function is returning a byte offset of the line and not a line number, but that should be easy enough to fix (as I did in the jsperf)

Comment: You need to add one to the length to account for the `\n` that was removed during split. `total_length += perLine[i].length + 1`

Comment: @brute_force username is accurate given solution. Do 100% of the work for each lookup, save nothing, get answer, rinse and repeat xD

Answer (score 1):

Similar to brute_force but with the off-by-1 error fixed. Also returns column number.

```js
const lines = code.split('\n')

function findLineColForByte(lines, index) {
  let totalLength = 0
  let lineStartPos = 0
  for (let lineNo = 0; lineNo < lines.length; lineNo++) {
    totalLength += lines[lineNo].length + 1 // Because we removed the '\n' during split.
    if (index < totalLength) {
      const colNo = index - lineStartPos
      return [lineNo + 1, colNo]
    }
    lineStartPos = totalLength
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that

> I need to do this hundreds of times after each other, so that's why it's relatively important it's efficient.

Most of these solutions require the computations to be done for each lookup, which means you are doing a lot of work over and over again.

To checkpoint some of these computations <strike>would</strike> (***could***) improve efficiency greatly.

Of course, first things first we need to split the lines up:

```js
/**
 * Returns a tuple (array with two elements) containing the split lines
 *     and whether or not the last character was a newLine
 *
 * @param {string} stringData The string to split
 *
 * @return {array} a tuple containing the lines
 *     and a boolean for if the last line has a newLine
 */
function splitLines( stringData ) {
    var lines = stringData.split("\n");
    if(stringData.slice(-1) === '\n') {
        lines.pop(); // Remove last empty line
        return [lines, true];
    } else {
        return [lines, false];
    }
}
```

This will ensure that our last line is not an empty string, if this is arbitrary, you don't need to check for this.

Next up is computing the cumulative character count for each line, that is, after line `x` there have been `n` total characters.

```js
/**
 * Returns an array with the cumulative character count from the beginning, 
 *     based on the line number
 *
 * @param {array} lineData The lines of the string
 * @param {boolean} lastLineHasNewLineChar Whether or not the last line had a newLineChar
 *
 * @return {array} The cumulative character counts for each line
 *     (e.g.) Line 0 has 18 chars plus a newLine, or 19; Line 1 has 8 chars, so 28, etc, etc.
 */
function buildLineEndingPositions( lineData, lastLineHasNewLineChar = false ) {
  var cumulativeSum = (sum => lineCharCount => sum += lineCharCount)(0); // Start sum at 0, keep adding the chars from each line.
  var numLines = lineData.length;
  var lineLengths = lineData.map( (line, index) => {
    if(numLines - 1 === index && !lastLineHasNewLineChar) {
        return line.length; // last line, last char was not a new line
    } else {
        return line.length + 1; // new line char was stripped
    }
  });
  return lineLengths.map(cumulativeSum);
}
```

Finally, we can compute these once, and access them for any number of future lookups based on character position to determine the line (the first index to be less than or equal to the cumulative character count)

```js
const testString = "There once was a guy from france\nHe really liked to dance\nUntil one day, his legs ran away\nIdk where I was going with this";

const [testLines, lastLineHadNewLineChar] = splitLines(testString);

const cumulativeCharCounts = buildLineEndingPositions(testLines, lastLineHadNewLineChar);

console.log(cumulativeCharCounts); //[33, 58, 91, 122]
```

By iterating through the `cumulativeCharCounts` we can now use the index to determine the line number with a simple boolean compare to the desired char position, until we reach the first cumulative position that is less than or equal to our desired position. The split and cumulative counts are figured out 1x and reused, thus less overhead for each of the hundreds of calls.

Answer (score -1):

```
// Let this be your 4MB string.
var str = "This \n is a\n test\n string."

// Let this be the index of the character you are finding within the 4MB string.
var index = str.indexOf("test")

// Create substring from beginning to index of character.
var substr = str.substring(0, index)

// Count the number of new lines.
var numberOfLines = (function(){
try{
   // Add 1 to final result to account for the first line.
   return substr.match(new RegExp("\n", "g")).length + 1
} catch(e){
  // Return 1 if none found because the character is found on the first line. 
  return 1 
}})()
```